# UIPickerView - Value transfer for calculating

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am new in swift. 
May be someone can help me.
I fill a pickerView with my own data.

Can I deposit a value behind the data?

The statement is:
If the Users pick some aperture on the `pickerView` the deposit value  (User can´t see the deposit value) should go to an label? for calculating farther?
example: apertue Ø 6(deposit value is 0,4)  label shows 0,4 ccm

```
import Foundation

class Balkenbewehrung : UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

let pickerData = ["Ø 6","Ø 8","Ø 10","Ø 12","Ø 14","Ø 16","Ø 20",
    "Ø 25","Ø 26","Ø 28","Ø 30","Ø 32","Ø 36","Ø 40","Ø 50"]



@IBOutlet weak var myPicker: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    myPicker?.delegate = self
    myPicker?.dataSource = self

}

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickerData.count
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    return pickerData[row]
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    myLabel.text = pickerData[row]
 }
}
```

Thanks from Germany

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build your data structure with pre calculated values and try this approach

```
    class ViewController : UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var myPicker: UIPickerView!

    var pickerDictionary: Dictionary<String, String> = ["Ø 6" : "0,4 ccm",
                                                        "Ø 8" : "0,6 ccm",
                                                        "Ø 10" : "0,8 ccm",
                                                        "Ø 12" : "0,10 ccm",
                                                        "Ø 14" : "0,12 ccm" ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        myPicker?.delegate = self
        myPicker?.dataSource = self
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerDictionary.count
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
        return pickerDictionary.keys.array[row]
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        myLabel.text = pickerDictionary[pickerDictionary.keys.array[row]]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. That looks good. How can I now take the value from mylabel.text to calculating (example * 2)?? I will add a button for calculating and a another label for the show the final result.

Comment: Show your formula, total number of textfields. i will help you out.

Comment: Thanks very lot. I try to explain, but my english is not the best. User will choose the Ø 6,8....in picker view .Behind the Ø will deposit values (0,4 ccm). See like your example above. This values should go to a calculating multiply with intake in new textfield. This result of the calculate must be show in a another textfield1. This textfield1 must accumulate and save all value that the user choose and calculate one below the other.  I hope you know what i mean and can help me. Greetings to india

Answer (score 0):

You Can do your calculation first then assign its value in `UILabel`

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
     // code your calculation here
      myLabel.text = yourResult
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But how i deposit a value behind the apertue Ø 6?

Answer (score 0):

i will try to help you with objective -c way:

create a class like this:

```
@interface PickerRowOption : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * apertue;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * deposit;

@end
```

build your data source array with objects instantiated from this class.

```
NSArray * pickerData = // containts PickerRowOption s
```

do some stuff and return aperture:

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
                       titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
                      forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
     PickerRowOption *option = [pickerdata objectAtIndex:row];

     //further calculations here....

     return option.aperture;
}
```